# Namespaces in R packages

Tags: r

How do people learn about giving an R package a namespace? I find the documention in "R Extensions" fine, but I don't really get what is happening when a variable is imported or exported - I need a dummy's guide to these directives.

How do you decide what is exported? Is it just everything that really shouldn't required the pkg:::var syntax? What about imports?

Do imports make it easier to ensure that your use of other package functions doesn't get confused when function names overlap?

Are there special considerations for S4 classes?

Packages that I'm familiar with that use namespaces such as sp and rgdal are quite complicated - are there simple examples that could make things clearer?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I have a start on an answer on the devtools wiki: https://r-pkgs.org/Metadata.html

Comment: @hadley  For packages I've created I now have to add a namespace for 2.14.  This thread is a bit above my understanding right now.  When I open up plyr's folder for instance I see a document named NAMSPACE. If I were to put this document with the same format as you have for my functions into my package folder would this be all I have to do.

Comment: @TylerRinker Yes, that's the gist of it.  Create an `export(...)` statement for each function you wish to export.  if you import packages, you will also need to add an `import(...)` statement for each package.  See also the answer by @DirkEddelbuettel on this page.

Comment: But best to use `roxygen2` to create it for you.

Comment: Just wondered recently whether it's possible to create namespaces interactively. Just like environments when using  `new.env()`. I understand they are used for packages, but still it would be nice when developing a larger script that's not a package. Does devtools offer something like this?

Comment: @MattBannert yes, but it's not really recommended - R exposes little of the namespace API so we've had to hack around it, doing things like extracting internal C code out of base R.

Comment: @hadley didn't mean to use it in production but rather to give non-R developers an easy entry to developing with R. So they wouldn't miss namespaces so badly while just creating a script, and then later on let them do it the R way, i.e. build a package.

Comment: @MattBannert not enough room to discuss in comments, but I don't see advantage of namespaces in scripts. Better to restart R between different scripts.

Comment: @hadley: ok you're right. about both, namespaces and comments. thanks though.

Answer (score 30):

Few years later here....

I consolidated findings from Chambers, other StackOverflow posts, and lots of tinkering in R:
https://blog.thatbuthow.com/how-r-searches-and-finds-stuff/

This is less about implementing NAMESPACE/IMPORTS/DEPENDS and more about the purpose of these structures.  Answers some of your questions.

Comment: Wonderfully clear (unlike the "Writing R Extensions" document...)

Answer (score 15):

The clearest explanation I've read is in John Chambers' [Software for Data Analysis: Programming with R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387759352), page 103. I don't know of any free online explanations that are better than what you've already found in the R Extensions manual.

Comment: thanks for that, reminds me that I've not read that yet - though I was excited to see it published

Comment: the explanation in this book is really detailed, exactly what I was after

Answer (score 12):

You could also pick an easy, small package and follow it.

I semi-randomly looked at [digest](http://cran.r-project.org/package=digest) which is one of my smaller packages. I loads a (small) dynamic library and exports one symbol, the `digest()` function.  Here is the content of the NAMESPACE file:

```
## package has dynamic library
useDynLib(digest)

## and one and only one core function
export(digest)
```

Have a look at the rest of the source files and maybe try to read *Writing R Extensions* alongside looking at the example, and do some experiments.

Comment: Nice, plus checksum algorithms  - I've been wondering if there was an Rc . . . I mean an R package for that ;)

Comment: Aye. Looking at the NAMESPACE files of existing packages is definitely the way I learned how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.stat.uiowa.edu/~luke/R/namespaces/morenames.pdf