# Questions of search() function

Tags: r, function, directory, package, workspace

I have some fundamental but, crucial questions after learning about search() function. 
I want answer for accurate meaning and relationships between packages, GlobalEnv, working directory and the workspace.

When I used the function, it says,

> search()
>   [1] ".GlobalEnv" "Autoloads" "package:base"

where ".GlobalEnv" is the workspace. Several sites say that workspace is the same as working directory. I wonder if ".GlobalEnv" is the same as the result of

> getwd()

code. Also I wonder if all the packages like "Base" are included in the ".GlobalEnv" or stored in somewhere else.

Comment: The question might seem quite silly but I am asking cause the concept and relationship of workspace, globalenvironment, working directory is not stated thoroughly.

Comment: Here are two links which you may find helpful: [Environments](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html) (from Hadley's Advanced R), [How R Searches and Finds Stuff](http://blog.obeautifulcode.com/R/How-R-Searches-And-Finds-Stuff/).

Comment: Semi-related posts on SO: [Namespaces in R packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371181/namespaces-in-r-packages), [Writing robust R code: namespaces, masking and using the :: operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947159/writing-robust-r-code-namespaces-masking-and-using-the-operator).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of whether this fully answers your question, anyway:

`.GlobalEnv` is the user's workspace, and is not the same as the working directory. It is where user-defined objects accumulate. From the help page of the function `environment()` :

> The global environment `.GlobalEnv`, more often known as the user's
>   workspace, is the first item on the search path. It can also be
>   accessed by `globalenv()`.

From the [R language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html), the definition of environment:

> Environments can be thought of as consisting of two things: a frame,
>   which is a set of symbol-value pairs, and an enclosure, a pointer to
>   an enclosing environment. When R looks up the value for a symbol the
>   frame is examined and if a matching symbol is found its value will be
>   returned. If not, the enclosing environment is then accessed and the
>   process repeated. Environments form a tree structure in which the
>   enclosures play the role of parents. The tree of environments is
>   rooted in an empty environment, available through `emptyenv()`, which
>   has no parent.

The base package is not contained in `.GlobalEnv`, but in a different environment called `.BaseNamespaceEnv`, and can be accessed also by `baseenv()`. You verify that the two environments contain different objects by comparing the output of `ls(globalenv())` and `s(baseenv())`.

When R looks up for something, it starts in the global enviroment, then if it doesn't find it there, it moves up to the enclosing (*parent*) environment, and so on. If you use the `parent.env()` function to follow the whole chain of parent environments, you will see that the base package is searched last, after any other loaded packages and just before the empty environment (into which nothing can be assigned).

```
e_ <- .GlobalEnv
while( !identical(e_, emptyenv()) )
{ 
    e_ <- parent.env(e_)
    print(e_)
}
```